# How do I find frequency of combinations where combinations are specified as multiple rows?

Tags: r, combinations

I am looking at location data and I have a list of individuals where I know specific locations and times. What I'm looking to understand is what are the most common combinations of locations within any given day.

```
id      location    date
00231   home        2014-01-02
00231   gas station 2014-01-02
00231   home        2014-01-02
02830   work        2014-01-02
02830   home        2014-01-02
00231   home        2014-01-04
00231   mcdonalds   2014-01-04
```

As you can see there can be many individuals with varying lengths of location groups. How can I use R to find the frequency of all the potential combinations (for both 'order matters' and 'order doesn't matter'). Here is what I would like to see:

```
combination                  freq
home-gas station-home        472
work-home                    439
home-walmart-home            209
```

Also to clarify, I don't need any other analytics on the locations for now, just looking for  a combination analysis.

Thanks & apologize if this is duplicate, but I couldn't find anything where the combinations were located on multiple rows (versus many of examples about combinations of variables/column values)

Comment: [How to summarize data by group in R?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8225/how-to-summarize-data-by-group-in-r)

Comment: Thanks Robert. Well, I'm looking for combinations of varying lengths. I don't want group by `location`, I'm looking for groups based on a `location group` across multiple (varying number) of rows

Comment: Look a little closer at that question, and generalize the technique to your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many ways - and I think robert is right in asking you to generalize

I am feeling generous - so with some generated data - some exaples with table and ddply (whihc outputs a data.frame)

```
data1 <- data.frame(value=1:100,group=factor(rep(1:4,25)))
table(data1$group)
ddply(data1,.(group),summarize,N=length(group))
ddply(data1,.(group),summarize,N=length(group),sum1=sum(value),mean1=mean(value))
```

Comment: Thanks @user1617979, I'm not very familiar with `ddply`, but when you have a group with varying sizes, this doesn't on its face seem to solve the problem. Maybe I don't know enough right now. I tried using the `aggregate` function to try and create a text string `aggregate(mydata, by = list(id, date), c)` .. Unfortunately my data has 300,000+ rows and after 30 mins the operations still hasn't finished. Was this the wrong use of it?

Comment: I am not familiar with aggregate, sorry. But deeply can be slow in some cases (adding option .progress="text" at least provides a progress bar). On did ply also you need to have the summarize option, or it will add the data to each row. I recently did it with millions of rows so I know it works, but also that it is slow (I also had an error in grouping by too many levels) . I searched on SO and found some good pieces on alternatives to dddply- good luck